# C++ Array as reference or as pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference, pass-by-value

In this program there is 2 functions: one to create an array, and another to delete it

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void create_array(int **&arr,int nrow, int ncol) {
    arr = new int*[nrow];
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i){
        arr[i] = new int[ncol];
        }
}

void clean_memory(int **&arr, int nrow, int ncol) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i) {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
}


int main()
{
    int nrow, ncol,element;
    int **arr;
    printf("Dynamic array \n");
    printf("Write down number of rows and number of columns \n");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &nrow, &ncol);
    create_array(arr,nrow, ncol);
    clean_memory(arr, nrow, ncol);
    cin.get();
    printf("Press Enter to exit \n");
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Why are we passing array to `create_array` as a reference, but we can't pass as pointer ( without `&`)?

Why can't i write like this:

```
void create_array(int **arr,int nrow, int ncol)
```

Same goes for `clean_memory`

Comment: Is there a reason you are using variable length C-arrays instead of just a std::vector?

Comment: @Corristo variable-length C arrays are not used here. `new` is a C++ feature

Comment: Oh, indeed :D Time to go to bed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't i write like this:
>
> ```
> void create_array(int **arr,int nrow, int ncol)
> ```

You finally want

```
int **arr;
```

to receive a value that was allocated in `create_array()` in `main()`, that's why its passed to

```
void create_array(int **&arr,int nrow, int ncol)
```

as reference.

It's not really needed to pass as reference to

```
void clean_memory(int **&arr, int nrow, int ncol)
```

unless you want to set the output parameter to `nullptr` after deleting:

```
void clean_memory(int **&arr, int nrow, int ncol) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i) {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
    arr = nullptr; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `createArray(arr,nrow, ncol)` with `create_array(int **arr,int nrow, int ncol)` as signature, `arr` will not be updated in the `main` function. It will keep its undefined value.

Even in `C` you have to call `createArray(&arr,nrow, ncol)` in order to update `arr` at the caller level. `C++` authorizes call by ref to simplify the reading, but the generated code would be the same as passing `&arr` by value.

Answer (score 0):

```
int **arr
```

Is a value which presents the address-of the address-of an int,

If you call a function with a parameter of this type, it passes by value, meaning the function has a discrete local copy of the source value.

Since the purpose of the function is to provide us with a value of this type it needs to either return such a value, take the address of our dest variable or take a reference.

```
int **arr = get(...);
get(&arr, ...);
// or opaquely by reference
get(arr, ...);
```